iOS: Writing multiple values to the Keychain atomically
Is there any way to write multiple values to the keychain atomically, in a single transaction to guarantee that they are all written successully, or in the event of any failure, none of them are written?
We have a bug in our app where we write 4 values one after the other (as part of a migration) but the logs report that some users only have 2 or 3 of these values present, presumably because the app is crashing mid-write.
Apple's SecItemAdd documentation suggests the following...

To add multiple items to a keychain at once use the kSecUseItemList key in the attributes dictionary with an array of dictionaries (each corresponding to one of the items) as its value. This is only supported for non-password items.

However it would seem kSecUseItemList is macOS only and not available on iOS.

How big are the items? Can you encode them as, say a json string, and then write that string as a single item?

Could you show the code you use ?
